# Thumbnails creator function not create the image inside the folder

Tags: php, gd

Using the following function

```
function crea_thumb($name,$filename,$new_w,$new_h){
$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($name);

$old_x=imageSX($src_img);
$old_y=imageSY($src_img);
if ($old_x > $old_y) {
    $thumb_w=$new_w;
    $thumb_h=$old_y*($new_h/$old_x);
}
if ($old_x < $old_y) {
    $thumb_w=$old_x*($new_w/$old_y);
    $thumb_h=$new_h;
}
if ($old_x == $old_y) {
    $thumb_w=$new_w;
    $thumb_h=$new_h;
}

$dst_img=ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);
imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);

imagejpeg($dst_img, $filename);

imagedestroy($dst_img); 
imagedestroy($src_img); 
}
```

I don't receive the thumbnail.

The call to the function is similar to this:

```
crea_thumb("/images/covers/big/44.jpg", "/images/covers/small/44.jpg", 400, 400);
```

Note that

> /images/covers/big/44.jpg

is already uploaded and the folder has 777 permissions.

Has anyone an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: is there any php warning/errors while create thumb ?

Comment: You should not ask here before doing any error handling at all in your code...